# New Facebook Messenger Webview Not Working

Tags: javascript, facebook, webview, facebook-messenger, messenger

I've been trying out the new [Messenger Webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview) that opens like a pop-up for URL instead of opening in a new tab.

And I wrote a small script to get user id as per this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/userid)

However, in Mobile apps, I'm able to get the user id. But opening on the website (both facebook.com/messages and messenger.com) it shows me an error:

> This SDK method is not supported on this Messenger client. Please
>   upgrade.

```
<body>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));
    window.extAsyncInit = function() {
      alert('loaded sdk');
    };
    function getUser() {
      MessengerExtensions.getUserID(function success(uids) {
        var psid = uids.psid;
        alert(JSON.stringify(psid));
      }, function error(err, errorMessage) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(errorMessage));
      });
    }
  </script>
  <input type="button" onclick="getUser()" value="Get user id" />
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Messenger Extensions SDK in the messenger web client, you should use `MessengerExtension.getContext()`. `MessengerExtensions.getUserID()` isn't supported in the web client.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that

Comment: is there any way to make it work on opening URL in a new tab? Right now it works only if it's inside the popup.